# EWS managed API. IsNew Always return false and can't use TextBody

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am a newbie developer and I have been stuck with EWS for hours now. I need to read through the most recent emails, get all the unread emails and use the data from them to do some stuff.

At this moment My code looks like this.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CertificateValidationCallBack;
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
        service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("support@mycompany.com", "mysupersuperdupersecretpassword");


        service.AutodiscoverUrl("support@mycompany.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);


        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,new ItemView(2));
        foreach (Item item in findResults.Items)
        {
            // works perfectly until here
            Console.WriteLine(item.Subject);
            Console.WriteLine('\n');
            item.Load();
            string temp = item.Body.Text;
            // I can't seem to get TextBody to work. so I used a RegEx                                                 Match match = Regex.Match(temp, "<body>.*?</body>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
            string result = match.Value;
            result = result.Replace("<body>", "");
            result = result.Replace("</body>", "");
            Console.Write(result);
            Console.WriteLine('\n');
            //Now the email boddy is fine but IsNew always returns false.
            if (item.IsNew)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This message is unread!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This message is read!");
            }
        }        


    }
```

I have googled and tried and googled some more and I am stuck. How do I now which emails are read, is there a way to get the email body text that's more effective than what I have done ? Any help would be super appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/hh312849%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) for usage is pretty good if you haven't already read it.

For your issue, cast your item to an EmailMessage

```
foreach (Item item in findResults.Items)
{
    var mailItem = (EmailMessage)item;
    // works perfectly until here
    Console.WriteLine(mailItem.Subject);
}
```

I did notice you are not using Property Sets, but having only used EWS for event notifications and not going through existing mails, it may be different.

*UPDATE Additions in light of your changes*

use this for your Property Set

```
new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties) {
    RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text
};
```

Also this reads a little nicer and uses the `Body.Text` property

```
foreach (Item myItem in findResults.Items.Where(i=>i is EmailMessage))
{
    var mailItem = myItem as EmailMessage;
    Console.WriteLine(mailItem.Subject);
    mailItem.Load(new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties) {
        RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text
    }); // Adding this parameter does the trick :)
    Console.WriteLine(mailItem.Body.Text);

    if(! mailItem.IsRead)
        Console.WriteLine("Who is Your Daddy!!!!");

}
```

Comment: I actually read a similar article to this one. I am going to post an answer showing what I have now. Which is a lot closer!!! Thank you for your reply.

Comment: ooooops.... I am a bit new to stack overflow... I will remember that for the next time

Comment: Added a little bit which may help with your TextBody

Comment: Nice Suggestion. Unfortunately I am still stuck with the Body. It returns a loooong HTML string. I also tried using mailItem.TextBody.Text; This does not work... it simply returns a null reference. Which makes sense since Item is higher u in the hierarchy than EmailMessage. Thanks for all your help. I'll try to figure something out. Worst case scenario. I use an HTML parser.

Comment: Just solved it. I am going to edit your answer and mark it as answer :)

Comment: The property set must be set for the EmailMessage class as well. I added this. This works 100% Thank you James for all your help!

Comment: Nice one, no worries.